How do I find a Resonators attack combos?
I have been trying to find out what the attacks are for each of my characters. I have done the Tutorial by clicking the bottom right button on the Resonator page.

...but the game doesn't seem to list them anywhere I can find.
Where can I find out what attacks a Resonator can do and their combos?

Just to check, do combos refer to the amount of times you spam the attack button in your question? Also, do you refer to something separate than the attack button attack? If not, it should be obvious? The combos are just the attacks that string together when you hit the attack button before the combo timer resets. (sorry the comment's hard to understand, I have trouble conveying ideas)

No, I mean attack combos, such as Danjin, having Atk, Atk, E, E as a specific combo

Seems these attacks are in the Forte page in the Resonator screen. Thanks to this guide I found it, https://wutheringwaves.gg/combat-basics/.

This will give you a page detailing the Resonators special combos. Here are Danjins for example.

